# The following packages have been kept back

Tags: debian, apt, aptitude, synaptic

```
The following packages have been kept back: click click-dev gir1.2-click-0.4 libclick-0.4-0 0
```

BUT

It's clear that all of these packages are either on hold somewhere, or are in some kind of conflict, or would cause conflict. I don't understand why or where. They are neither Locked in Synaptic, nor Held back by `apt` or `aptitude`.

I am curious as to why these packages are held back? I cannot get past this with `apt-get dist-upgrade`, or with `apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade`.

I am on Linux Mint 17.3.

`apt-cache policy click click-dev gir1.2-click-0.4 libclick-0.4-0`:

```
click:
  Installed: 0.4.42+16.04.20151229-0~467~ubuntu14.04.1
  Candidate: 0.4.43+16.04.20160203-0~606~ubuntu14.04.1
  Version table:
     0.4.43+16.04.20160203-0~606~ubuntu14.04.1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
 *** 0.4.42+16.04.20151229-0~467~ubuntu14.04.1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.4.21.1ubuntu0.2 0
        500 http://mirror.vutbr.cz/ubuntu/archive/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     0.4.21.1 0
        500 http://mirror.vutbr.cz/ubuntu/archive/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
click-dev:
  Installed: 0.4.42+16.04.20151229-0~467~ubuntu14.04.1
  Candidate: 0.4.43+16.04.20160203-0~606~ubuntu14.04.1
  Version table:
     0.4.43+16.04.20160203-0~606~ubuntu14.04.1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
 *** 0.4.42+16.04.20151229-0~467~ubuntu14.04.1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.4.21.1ubuntu0.2 0
        500 http://mirror.vutbr.cz/ubuntu/archive/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     0.4.21.1 0
        500 http://mirror.vutbr.cz/ubuntu/archive/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
gir1.2-click-0.4:
  Installed: 0.4.42+16.04.20151229-0~467~ubuntu14.04.1
  Candidate: 0.4.43+16.04.20160203-0~606~ubuntu14.04.1
  Version table:
     0.4.43+16.04.20160203-0~606~ubuntu14.04.1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
 *** 0.4.42+16.04.20151229-0~467~ubuntu14.04.1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.4.21.1ubuntu0.2 0
        500 http://mirror.vutbr.cz/ubuntu/archive/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     0.4.21.1 0
        500 http://mirror.vutbr.cz/ubuntu/archive/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
libclick-0.4-0:
  Installed: 0.4.42+16.04.20151229-0~467~ubuntu14.04.1
  Candidate: 0.4.43+16.04.20160203-0~606~ubuntu14.04.1
  Version table:
     0.4.43+16.04.20160203-0~606~ubuntu14.04.1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
 *** 0.4.42+16.04.20151229-0~467~ubuntu14.04.1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.4.21.1ubuntu0.2 0
        500 http://mirror.vutbr.cz/ubuntu/archive/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     0.4.21.1 0
        500 http://mirror.vutbr.cz/ubuntu/archive/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

DEBUG:

```
apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=true install click click-dev gir1.2-click-0.4 libclick-0.4-0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  python3-click-package
Suggested packages:
  ubuntu-app-launch-tools upstart-app-launch-tools
Recommended packages:
  debootstrap
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  python3-click
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python3-click-package
The following packages will be upgraded:
  click click-dev gir1.2-click-0.4 libclick-0.4-0
4 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 146 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,024 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

REPRODUCTION of the PROBLEM:

```
apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  click click-dev gir1.2-click-0.4 libclick-0.4-0
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
```

AFTER FIX:

```
apt-get install click click-dev gir1.2-click-0.4 libclick-0.4-0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
click-dev is already the newest version.
click-dev set to manually installed.
click is already the newest version.
libclick-0.4-0 is already the newest version.
libclick-0.4-0 set to manually installed.
gir1.2-click-0.4 is already the newest version.
gir1.2-click-0.4 set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and specify which distribution you're running (including its version), and where you installed `click` from if it didn't come from your distribution.

Comment: @StephenKitt How do I know where the package came from?

Comment: `apt-cache policy click click-dev gir1.2-click-0.4 libclick-0.4-0` will tell you, and might even give some idea why they're being kept back.

Comment: @StephenKitt I edited the question in order to give you the info

Comment: Try running `apt-get` with the flag `-o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=true`.and please give the command and complete output.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Did I call it right? It seems not to recognize the command. http://i.imgur.com/IBHIlMi.png

Comment: @burian.vlastimil You don't actually give any command. You need `apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=true install pkgname1 pkgname2` or similar.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I edited the question in order to give you the info

Comment: I'm confused. I thought you said the packages were held back. Please paste the same command and its output with the debug flag as well, along the version with the debug flag.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I only thought so. I now looked at all places (apt, aptitude, synaptic) and none of those packages are on hold anywhere. So, you did resolve the problem ;) Please post it as an answer and I will accept it. But I am unsure, whether to install some recommended or suggested packages (?) Thank you once more.

Comment: @burian.vlastimil I didn't do anything. If you can't reproduce the problem, I suggest you either close or delete the question.

Comment: @FaheemMitha You did. I can reproduce the problem. See edit.

Comment: @burian.vlastimil Ok. Can you run the same command as you did with the debug flag, but this time without the debug flag, please? I.e. `apt-get install click click-dev gir1.2-click-0.4 libclick-0.4-0`. You can put it after the `dist-upgrade` command. You don't need to remove anything. Just add the command and the output at the end of the question.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Already solved by your first suggestion. Please post an answer for people to know this command. I haven't yet seen it. Thanks again.

Comment: @burian.vlastimil Can you run the command `apt-get install click click-dev gir1.2-click-0.4 libclick-0.4-0` and post the output please? That way, we'll have some idea what is going on. I don't think the debug output should make any difference, but I see no point in guessing. Also, please give the command you ran to produce the output at the very beginning of the question, namely `The following packages have been kept back: click click-dev gir1.2-click-0.4 libclick-0.4-0 0`.

Comment: @FaheemMitha As I said you've already fixed it ;)

Comment: @burian.vlastimil Ok. I've added an answer. However, for the sake of completeness, can you add the command you originally ran at the beginning of the question? You only give part of the output. It is always better to show the *complete* command and the *complete* output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the poster, the following command works

```
apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=true install click click-dev gir1.2-click-0.4 libclick-0.4-0
```

and gives the result

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  python3-click-package
Suggested packages:
  ubuntu-app-launch-tools upstart-app-launch-tools
Recommended packages:
  debootstrap
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  python3-click
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python3-click-package
The following packages will be upgraded:
  click click-dev gir1.2-click-0.4 libclick-0.4-0
4 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 146 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,024 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

So, no problem showed up when running an explicit `apt-get install`.

I asked the poster to run it without the debug flag to see whether it gave the same results, but apparently he had already run the debug version.

Answer (score 3):

This happens when the dependencies of the identified packages changed and new packages need to be installed. We need to use dist-upgrade in order to install the new dependencies and upgrade the packages:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

checks for broken dependencies

```
apt-get check
```

Fix Broken Packages

```
apt-get -f install
```

remove .deb files for packages that are no longer installed on your system

```
apt-get autoclean
```

Put the desired package on hold

```
echo "<package_name> hold" | dpkg --set-selections
```

Reconfigure the named package:

```
dpkg-reconfigure <package_name>
```

Comment: That's one of the reasons it can happen, but not the only one.  Another possibility is that one of the held-back packages' dependencies is not available yet (common when running, e.g. debian sid or testing).  Yet another is when the held-back package(s) (or their dependencies) conflict with another already-installed or about-to-be-installed package.

Answer (score 2):

After upgrading versions/packages the error "The following packages have been kept back" can indeed happen every so often.

Either the packages were installed from another repository, or due to not so frequent packages errors, some dependency is not being satisfied, or other requirements that cannot be satisfied without user intervention, including the decision of major upgrades between somewhat incompatible versions of a particular package.

In some cases, it is enough to do an apt-get install packages names, in others it is necessary to add the missing repository.

Concerning you case, I found this thread:

[Snappy developer tools](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/snappy-app-devel/2015-April/000150.html)

> It seems the ubuntu-device-flash package in beta PPA needs the
>   dependency package "click-ubuntu-policy" which could not be found in
>   Trusty, add ppa:snappy-dev/tools then I think snappy-tools could be
>   installed, could you help verify this solution and file a bug about
>   this issue?